# Namespace refactoring tool for Eclipse?

Tags: c++, eclipse, refactoring, namespaces, eclipse-plugin

I'm doing some housekeeping on some files, and I need to move some classes to a new namespace.  Currently I have to manually edit the files, but I was wondering if there's a more efficient way of doing this?

I heard about ReSharper for Visual Studio does what I need, but is there a similar tool for Eclipse?

Comment: You might consider tagging this question "c++" rather than "c" since C doesn't support neither classes nor namespaces.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I'm not really sure if Eclipse does that but [IntelliJ IDEA](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/) (from the same vendor as ReSharper) does have a refactoring to move classes between packages. It is available from Refactor > Migrate menu if I remember correctly.

Comment: Ah, my fault. For some reason I thought the question was related to Java. Just as a note, IntelliJ has a C/C++ support plugin (http://plugins.intellij.net/plugin/?id=1373) but it's nowhere near the core product's Java functionality. Sorry for the confusion and please disregard the answer.

Comment: Haven't deserved an accept resolution for this answer but thanks anyway

Answer (score 0):

> is there a similar tool for Eclipse?

Nope.

Comment: LOL , excellent answer ! simple straightforward, no alternatives.

Answer (score 0):

The is no such capability in eclipse until today MARS 8.1 . However, what on can do is to manually search for occurrences of the classes.

1. Select the class name that you want to refactor and to a File Search within the enclosing project.
2. From the tabs select "File Search" and then press "Replace ..." , it will find all occurences and let you fill in the replacement text.
3. Click "Preview" to see what is going to be applied and remove those actions that you do not wish that they be applied by unchecking them.

This should be sufficient. If you are using `git` you can always do `git checkout -b _refactorme` to feel safe and then merge your changes. In that manner if something went wrong you can always track the problem e.g. using `git blame`.