# C++ refactoring to add a namespace to all classes and functions?

Tags: c++, ide, refactoring

I have a C++ project with hundreds of files, and I need to enclose all its classes and functions in an additional namespace. Is there a tool that can do that automatically?

(There was a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3883380/namespace-refactoring-tool-for-eclipse) before, but it was about Eclipse specifically and it's a year old, so maybe there are some additional answers now?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a shell script for this purpose; see an [example](http://blog.xenim.de/moving-c-plus-plus-code-in-namespace/) here

And here are some [common thoughts](http://www.gotw.ca/publications/migrating_to_namespaces.htm) on the issue

Comment: That's a pretty nice script (and license). The idea of finding the last include is clever.

Comment: The "example" is now a dead link, unfortunately.